# How to compute average deaths in population at the end of a period?

Tags: mean, population

Wondering if you can help with solution for this. (I run a simple simulation to get the answer currently)...

There is a pool of resources. Every day a resource can become unavailable (die) or just grow older. There is a process that fills the resource pool to the required size (N) in case one or more deaths occur.

A resource can live for x days where minAge <= x <= maxAge. The life expectancy of a resource occurs with equal probability within that range.

So how can I answer the question: "How many resources are replaced every day given 
pool size N and the min/max age range".

Comment: As a first attempt for a steady state, perhaps something like $\dfrac{2N}{\text{min age}+\text{max age}}$ based on the reciprocal of the rate based on the average life expectancy

Comment: Thanks a lot, this formula gives results consistent with the simulation :)